# clang++ not accepting use of template template parameter when using CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, crtp

I'm getting compilation errors when trying to call the base class constructor in derived initialization list when using a template template parameter with CRTP.

**Problem can be replicated with this snippet of code:**

```
template <template<class> class Derived, class T>
struct base
{
};

template <class T>
struct derived : public base<derived, T>
{
    derived()
        : base<derived, T>()
    { }
};
```

**The offending error messsage:**

```
bug.cpp:10:16: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
        : base<derived, T>()
               ^
bug.cpp:10:11: error: expected class member or base class name
        : base<derived, T>()
          ^
bug.cpp:10:11: error: expected '{' or ','
3 errors generated.
```

This problem only appears to happen on clang (3.4), not g++ (4.8, 4.7, 4.6). I'm compiling with -std=c++11 also.

This is the first time I've needed to use CRTP with template template parameter. Am I doing this okay and it's a problem with clang++ or not?

I've grown to trust clang++ error messages more than g++ of late!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is legal.

From the C++11 Standard, section 14.6.1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). **The injected-class-name can be used as a template-name** or a type-name. **When it is used** with a template-argument-list, **as a template-argument for a template template-parameter**, or as the final identiﬁer in the elaborated-type- speciﬁer of a friend class template declaration, **it refers to the class template itself**.

Looks like your version of `clang` is still implementing the old rule.  Based on your additional comments, it might be doing so only in the *ctor-initializer-list*.

---

User [David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) provided a workaround for compilers that haven't fully implemented the C++11 injected-class-name rule.  Use any name of the class that isn't unqualified, for example:

```
derived()
    : base< ::derived, T >()
//          ^^ qualified with global namespace
{ }
```

Some compilers may require this in the inheritance list also:

```
template <class T>
struct derived : public base< ::derived, T >
//                            ^^
```

Comment: +1 Did not know that this had changed in C++11. You might want to provide the workaround I had in the now deleted answer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: no worries, the new Standard still surprises me frequently.

Comment: I am not worried, on the contrary I learned something. I'd be worried the day I don't learn anything new :)

Comment: Note that you need [whitespace between `<` and `::`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bc0dcc3299d98f5d4d5ee6a95933c7ac-0e5891ff8107f561b22ca21b6b60d875) in C++03.

Comment: @JesseGood: Trigraphs strike again?  Oh, actually one of the digraphs (`<:` -> `[`).  Anyway, fixed.

Comment: @Jesse: Wow, C++11 made an exception to maximal munch for that exact case: "Otherwise, if the next three characters are `<::` and the subsequent character is neither `:` nor `>`, the `<`
is treated as a preprocessor token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token `<:`"  2.5p3

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for digging up the quote. It seems this rule was made especially for this case.

Comment: Someone post this bug?

Comment: @tower120: It affects an old version of clang.  Are you still seeing this with the latest version?

Comment: @BenVoigt Coliru sees, so ... Yeah... If 3.4 is new enough... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72b49073970a3551

Comment: @tower120: 3.4 is the same version used in the question, one year ago.  Try with the latest development version before worrying about a bug report.