# Error when using template class as template template-parameter in member variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am using templates in my C++ project, and I'm having an issue when using a templated type as a template template-parameter. I think the best way to describe it is to give an example that produces the error:

```
template <template<class> class P, typename T>
class Foo {
    P<T> baz;
};

template <class T>
class Bar {
    Foo<Bar, T> memberFoo;

    void makeFoo() {
        Foo<Bar, T>* f = new Foo<Bar, T>();
    }
};

Foo<Bar, int> globalFoo;
```

The declaration of `globalFoo` causes no error, but the declarations of `memberFoo` and `f` cause the compiler error:

> error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template
>   or type alias template

The error only occurs when using Bar as a template parameter inside of the declaration of the Bar class, but occurs using both clang and g++. This seems like something that would be documented somewhere, but googling yields no SO questions or other documentation.

Is this use of templates simply not legal in C++, or am I misunderstanding something about how to define and use templates? If this design architecture is not allowed by the C++11 standard, what is a workaround I can use?

Comment: I think the problem is that, within the definition of `Bar`, plain name `Bar` refers to *this* specialization - that is, `Bar<T>` - rather than the template as a whole. One workaround: add `template <typename U> using Bar2 = Bar<U>;` at the top of `Bar` definition, and use `Bar2` in place of `Bar` where you need to refer to the unspecialized template.

Comment: This seems recursive. Bar has a Foo member, but that Foo is templated such that it has the exact same Bar member as the class it is a part of. So Bar<T> contains itself, which isn't allowed. The particular error is caused by trying to use Bar as a template template parameter during its definition, without a forward declaration, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that an incomplete type is yielded at time of instantiation. Clang and G++ yield different errors because Clang (apparently) doesn't implement a C++11 rule that the injected class name can refer to the class template itself when used as a template template parameter (Igor's suggestion doesn't work btw.) Changing `Bar` to `::Bar` fixes this error, which makes Clang point out the incomplete error like G++ does. Changing `baz` to `P<T>*` allows it to compile.

**N.B.** Even though it *compiles*, it probably is undefined behavior. I suggest redesigning your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Igor 's comment, I have figured out a couple of workarounds for this issue. Are based on the fact that *referencing* `Bar` *within its declaration refers to this specialization of* `Bar` (to quote @Igor).

Note that all of these workarounds rely on the fact that `baz` can be declared as a pointer. `baz` not being a pointer causes a recursion issue that was mentioned by @Nir in the comments and leads to the error:

> field has incomplete type 'Foo<Bar<int>, int>'

**Workaround 1**

Add a forward declaration of `Bar` and create a template alias `Bar2`. For this to compile, `baz` must be a pointer:

```
template <template <typename> class P, typename T>
class Foo {
    P<T>* baz;
};

template<typename T> class Bar;
template <typename U> using Bar2 = Bar<U>;

template <class T>
class Bar {
    Foo<Bar2, T> memberFoo;

    void makeFoo() {
        Foo<Bar2, T>* f = new Foo<Bar2, T>();
    }
};

Foo<Bar, int> globalFoo;
```

The forward declaration and use of a template alias forces the compiler to use the unspecialized version of `Bar` when defining `memberFoo` and `f`, whereas it defaults to using the unspecialized version in the definition of `globalFoo`.

**Workaround 2**

This workaround is based on @user5800314's answer. I feel no need to re-state his workaround, but I do feel that it is worth noting the reason why it works.

I have read a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687459/clang-not-accepting-use-of-template-template-parameter-when-using-crtp) about injected class names and C++11, but the important difference here is that my code does not compile on g++, whereas theirs does. I do not believe that the issue is a lack of implementation of injected class names. I believe that this workaround fixes the compilation error because using `::Bar` instead of `Bar` again forces the compiler to access the global (unspecialized) version of `Bar` instead of accessing the local (specialized) version of `Bar`.

**Workaround 3**

Specify `Foo` as having a class (or typename) template-parameter instead of a template template-parameter, and be explicit about which specialization is being used whenever using the `Foo` template. This also requires that `baz` is a pointer, and that it does not use a template type:

```
template <class P, typename T>
class Foo {
    P* baz;
};

template <class T>
class Bar {
    Foo<Bar, T> memberFoo;

    void makeFoo() {
        Foo<Bar, T>* f = new Foo<Bar, T>();
    }
};

Foo<Bar<int>, int> globalFoo;
```

This workaround resolves the of potential confusion of template template-parameters by requiring that a specific class is provided to the `Foo` template. This workaround may not be usable in some cases, but may be an elegant solution in others. In my case, for instance, I will not need to instantiate an instance of `Foo` from outside of `Bar`, so this is a very nice way of getting around the compile error.

**P.S.** I really would like to credit @user5800314, since his workaround does *work*, however I provide a different explanation here, and since the explanation I provide here is what I believe is correct, I don't feel that I can mark @user5800314 's answer as accepted.

Comment: Some of the workarounds you've posted are honestly quite weird. I think this is a sort of X-Y situation, you may be better off trying to tell people what you are trying to do. I mean, are you trying to write a recursive data structure? It's unusual, and relatively rarely a good idea (in C++) for data structures to have pointers to other instances of their class.

Comment: I'm just sharing the things that I've found to make this class structure work. I  am passing data around between various modules (represented here by the `Bar` class. They have to know which other modules they are connected to, and the connections are described by the `Foo` class. Is there a better way to describe modules and their connections using C++?